# Using Java to modify AWS file?

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, configuration, webserver

I would like to build a centOS 7 instance on AWS and install Apache to build web server.
After that, I would like to modify the config file, /etc/hosts and /etc/httpd/conf.d/test.conf where test.conf is created by me.

Can I use java to modify the file directly? Or I should create the file and replace the old file on instance? I am little bit confused for the feasibility. Please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a few questions here, so I've split them out.

Q: Can I use programming language X to modify a file on the local filesystem?
A: Yes, with very few exceptions. For Java, yes (if the instance has a JRE).

Q: Should I use Java?
A: Probably not the first choice (you could probably do what you need in a shell script at launch).

Q: Should I create the Apache config files dynamically or build them into an [AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)?
A: Difficult to answer without more information. There are pros and cons to AMIs. If it's simple and quick to create/modify the files on launch, then I'd do it that way.

DevOps is a big subject and there are many options available to you for bootstrapping EC2 instances. Pre-baked AMIs is one option. Another simple option that you might consider is to write [userdata scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), that run at launch time, and that set up the instance for you (see simple [nginx example](https://geekylane.com/bootstrap-scripts-with-ec2-instance/)). They can install software, modify config files, start services, and other things. They can also pull collateral such as pre-staged config files from S3, which can be a handy option.

Comment: The reason for me using Java is Java is the language we are using.
Thank you so much! Its helpful for me!